# order by strings and numbers starting with numbers first and then 'strings of numbers'

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a varchar field in my table with various entries. How can I use the order by statement to get the following result:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
Steinstrass 1
Steinstrass 2
Steinstrass 3
Steinstrass 4
Steinstrass 5
Steinstrass 6
Steinstrass 7
Steinstrass 8
Steinstrass 9
Steinstrass 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
mysql> select * from sorting;
+---------+
| field1  |
+---------+
| 1       |
| 4       |
| 10      |
| Item 1  |
| Item 10 |
| Item 0  |
| 0       |
+---------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select field1 from sorting order by length(field1),field1 asc;
+---------+
| field1  |
+---------+
| 0       |
| 1       |
| 4       |
| 10      |
| Item 0  |
| Item 1  |
| Item 10 |
+---------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
order by (case when left(str, 1) between '0' and '9' then 1
               else 0
          end) desc,
         (case when left(str, 1) between '0' and '9' then cast(str as unsigned)
          end),
         cast(substring(str, instr(' ', str)+1, 100) as unsigned)
```

This should work for arbitrary initial strings.  It assumes there is a space between the initial string and the number.